# TCP socket programming using python in different computer systems

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to run TCP client and server socket program using Python in different system(system A=windows7(python2.7) & system B=windows10(python 3.6)). server program is running in system B but when client is executed in system A it(client prg) terminates after few seconds displaying message:

> ERROR 10060::connection failed because connected party didn't properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to response

CLIENT program for lower to uppercase

```
from socket import *
import socket
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect(('192.168.43.130',9067))
sentence = input('Input lowercase sentence:')
clientSocket.send(sentence.encode())
modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024).decode()
print ('From Server:', modifiedSentence)
clientSocket.close()
```

SERVER PROGRAM lower to uppercase

```
from socket import *
import socket
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',9067))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print ('The server is ready to receive')
while 1:
    connectionSocket,  addr = serverSocket.accept()
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print("String from client-->",sentence)
    capitalizedSentence = sentence.upper()
    print("String in server-->",capitalizedSentence)
    connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence.encode())
    print("-------------------------")
    connectionSocket.close()
```

Comment: I would start by collecting the input and then opening the socket. Right now you're opening the socket and then holding for user input. Is your 'server' receiving the message or is it failing before that?

Comment: server is not receiving message from client and keeps on running while displaying 'The server is ready to receive'

Comment: Are you sure you are better off writing a custom socket client/server system from scratch, rather than using some existing standard whether SOAP for Web services or ssh/telnet for interactive?

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a streaming protocol and you cannot assume you get the bytes you send in the same 'chunks' out of the receiving end. You'll need to decide on a framing solution. Often used approaches are using an agreed-upon termination character (such as \0 or newline) or first sending the length of a message followed by exactly that number of bytes of message payload.